# What’s God’s purpose David was talking about in psalm 57:2

Tags: christology, 2-chronicles, body-of-christ, pastorals, throne-of-god

Psalm 57:2 says, “I cry out to God Most High, to God who fulfills his purpose for me.” This is key in understanding God’s purpose for your life. God has numbered your days and will fulfill every purpose He has for you. What is God’s purpose David was talking about?

Comment: KJV '_that performs all things for me_' YLT '_who is perfecting for me_'

Answer (score 1):

In the beggining of that Psalm, we can read in [NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2057&version=NASB)

> Prayer for Rescue from Persecutors.
>
> For the music director; set to Al-tashheth. A Mikhtam of David, **when he fled from Saul in the cave**.

This was a prayer for aid. Why would David need aid? As the beginning also implies, David fled from Saul to a cave (1 Samuel 22:1-2).

Given the context, the purpose God would accomplish for David could be protection from his enemies and/or vengeance.

Answer (score 1):

English Standard Version

> I cry out to God Most High, to God who **fulfills his purpose for me**.

It is important to point out that the word "purpose" is not in the original Hebrew.

New American Standard Bible

> I will cry to God Most High, To God who **accomplishes all things for me**.

who fulfills
גֹּמֵ֥ר (gō·mêr)
**Verb** - Qal - Participle - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 1584: To end, come to an end, complete

His purpose for me.
עָלָֽי׃ (‘ā·lāy)
**Preposition** | first person common singular
Strong's Hebrew 5921: Above, over, upon, against

Not only the word "purpose" is not there, but also there is not even a noun. It is up to the translators to fill in the blank: God fulfills/completes/accomplishes ___ for me.

A similar occurrence is in Psalm 138:8a:

New International Version

> The LORD will **vindicate me**;

English Standard Version

> The LORD will **fulfill his purpose for me**

There is plenty of room for ambiguity here. David might not have been talking about a specific purpose in this verse. The rest of the psalms bear this out.

> 3 He sends from heaven and saves me, rebuking those who hotly pursue me ...
> 4 I am in the midst of lions; I am forced to dwell among ravenous beasts  ...
> 6 They spread a net for my feet—I was bowed down in distress.
> They dug a pit in my path—but they have fallen into it themselves.

It is just a general sense of God's protection over David so that he could finish his jobs.